# How to add deserialize method to abstract class

Tags: c#, json, .net-core

I have an idea, but I don't understand how to do it.

I've created an `abstract class AJsonSerializer`. And there I want to `Serialize` and `Deserialize` classes.

```
public abstract class AJsonSerializer {
  public string ToJson() {
    return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(this);
  }

  public T FromJson<T>(string jsonString) where T : class {
    return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(jsonString);
  }
}
```

I have a class `User` where I inherited from my abstract class:

```
public class User : AJsonSerializer {
  public string PublicKey { get; set; }
  public int User_ID { get; set; }
}
```

And now I can do like that

```
internal static void Get_UserData(string username, ref User user) {
  if (ReadFromCache(username, out string value)) {
    user = user.FromJson<User>(value);
  } else {
    DataAccess.Get_UserData(username, out string user_public_key, out int id_user);

    user.PublicKey = user_public_key;
    user.User_ID = id_user;

    value = user.ToJson();

    SaveToCashe(username, value);
  }
}
```

This row looks ugly: `user = user.FromJson<User>(value);`

I want to do it like that: `user.FromJson(value);`

I know how I can do it in class `User` (example below), but I want to do it in abstract class and then this method will work for all my classes

**Bad method how to solve it, just add initializer to class `User` like there:**

```
public User(string jsonString) {
  User user = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ApiUser>(jsonString);
  PublicKey = user.PublicKey;
  User_ID = user.User_ID;
}
```

Comment: Don't do this. This violates SRP. Keep serialization separate from model (`User`). Models must not know how they could be serialized and stored.

Comment: The question is: Why are you doing this? Why not use `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject` directly? Also the other Dennis is making a good point as well.

Comment: I agree with previous comments. I cant see any benefit of having the serialization as part of the class itself. In `Get_UserData` just call `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject` directly instead.

Comment: @DennisKuypers @Dennis Interesting point, but I just want to simplify my code where I need to  `Deserialize` class. And then in every classes use custom desirializer from json-string. And after I can use it for testing instead of Mock-classes I've just will store some json-strings

Comment: @IgorCova If different classes needs custom serialization you can add the `JsonConverterAttribute` to the class and point to a specific serialization class to handle that case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar to Jerries answer, another option is just an extension method. You can have a constraint for T to be a AJsonSerializer to have it limited only to the subtypes of it. You can't override the extension method, but in your code you don't have it as virtual in the first place.

```
public static class SerializerExtensions {
   public static T FromJson<T>(this T obj, string json) where T:AJsonSerializer  {
       JsonConvert.PopulateObject(json, obj);
       return obj;
   }
}
```

This way you won't need to implement passing of generic type throughout the inheritance chain. 
But you need to initialize the value to access, so it would be:

```
var user = new User();
user.FromJson(jsonSTring);
```

or

```
var user = SerializerExtensions.FromJson(new User(), jsonString);
```

It's your decision what fits your use case better.

Comment: Very nice answer. And this don't violates SRP. note for @Dennis

Comment: But it makes no sense. You create a user object just have call en extension on it to have it replaced by another instance.

Comment: @Magnus, good point. I changed it to PopulateObject, so now it populates the initial instance, instead of creating a new one.

Comment: And after `PopulateObject` we also can cut `return obj`

Comment: Well that depends on your use case. You can return it, if you want to have one line assign and create, if you don't use it that way, you can cut it.

Answer (score 1):

You could declare the generic type in your class definition

```
public class User : AJsonSerializer<User>
{
    public string PublicKey { get; set; }
    public int User_ID { get; set; }
}
```

```
public abstract class AJsonSerializer<T>
    where T : class
{
    public string ToJson() {
        return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(this);
    }

    public static T FromJson(string jsonString) {
        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(jsonString);
    }
}
```

Edit: and as Kara stated in his comment, your `FromJson` method can be static. So you can call it like

```
var user = User.FromJson(jsonString);
```

Comment: `FromJson()` should be `static`. You don't need an instance of your class to deserialize.

Comment: True, I just copied and pasted the op's code, I didn't really read it.